# batch - dynamic labels or functions

Tags: batch-file, dynamic, cmd, label, goto

I'm making a batch text adventure (because it's the easiest language to do so in, requiring barely any coding experience) and I want to know if there is a way to make dynamic `goto`s or labels.

For example, I have a dynamic health and energy system which displayes diferent health bars, depending on the health variable which is aquired from a save file on the `C:/` drive.

This requires quite a bit of code, and it would be much easier if I could just call a function.

As an alternative, I'd like to have a a dynamic goto. What I mean is a variable, and then a goto function.

```
:foo
set currentlbl="foo-"
echo Hello!
goto foo2

:foo-
echo %test%
pause
exit

:foo2
if "test"=="chizzits" set test2="derp"
if "test"=="chuzzits" set test2="herp"
goto %currentlbl%
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as goto commands do not recognize variables. Is there a way past this?

Comment: BTW, if your looking for an easy programming language, for simple text based games - USE `PYTHON`

Comment: True, it is simple to write a trivial program using Windows batch. But it is actually quite difficult to write a well constructed sophisticated program like a text adventure. You will need a lot of arcane knowledge and ugly hacks to do what is very simple in most languages. And debugging of a large batch script can be a real challenge. If you really insist on using batch, you might want to look at my port of the original Adventure to batch at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4876&p=28277#p28277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they can, remove the quotes in the `set` command, or place quotes in the label.

```
set currentlbl=foo-
:foo-
```

or

```
set currentlbl="foo-"
:"foo-"
```