# Batch file game loading to section

Tags: batch-file, cmd, goto

I'm making a sort of text based story game and RPG, and I'm labelling each "section", as I call it, with a tag. A section is basically any directed goto, like `:section1`. You get to `:section1` by having `goto section1`.

I've assigned each screen with a tag using a system of letters and numbers. What I've done is used a simple save/load code using `.sav`, and am using the following.

Save:

```
(
  echo %tag%
  echo %points%
  echo %weapon%
) > savegame.sav
```

Load:

```
< savegame.sav (
  set /p tag=
  set /p points=
  set /p weapon=
)
```

The game is linear, by the way. What I'm trying to attempt is upon load, I gather the tag and go to that screen associated with the tag. For example, if I saved the game at tag 23, I want to be able to load in tag 23 and automatically go into section 23 without having to manually type in `if %tag% == 23 goto 23`. Is there a way to do this quickly?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].  I don't see an actual question in there.  Are you having trouble with a particular piece of code?

Comment: Sorry, I'll shorten it. I'm not having trouble with the code, but rather, looking for a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch - dynamic labels or functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260918/batch-dynamic-labels-or-functions)

Comment: So you basically just want `goto %savedLabel%` yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Save Game Loaded.
IF %tag%==02 goto tag02
IF %tag%==03 goto tag03


:tag02
IF NOT %tag%==02 set tag=02
(your save code goes here)
echo this is tag02
:tag03
IF NOT %tag%==03 set tag=03
(your save code goes here)
echo this is tag03
```

It tried to keep it simple. But you can do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable as destination:

```
@echo off
set "tag=213"
goto :%tag% 
this line is never reached.

:23
echo reached 23
goto :eof
```

You can also combine with a fix string `goto :Section%tag%` and `:Section23` as label.

(Note: the colon in `goto :destination` is optional. I like it for clarity, others don't. Pick your choice)